# Problema al enviar puntero a array como parametro a una función

Tags: c++, c

Hola tengo un código como este:

```
int * vectorizar(int n){
    int numero[4];

    for(int i=3; i >= 0; i--){
        if(n != 0){
            numero[i] = n%10;
            n /=10;
        }else{
            numero[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    return numero;
}

int ascendente(int * n){  <---- PROBLEMA !!!!!
    printf("Digito mas significativo: %d\n",n[0]);
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int * ejemplo = vectorizar(n);

    printf("Numero vectorizado: %d %d %d %d\n",ejemplo[0],ejemplo[1],ejemplo[2], ejemplo[3]);

    printf("Numero ordenado ascendentemente: %d\n",ascendente(ejemplo));


    return 0;
}
```

El problema ocurre en la función "ascendente" que al imprimir n[0] me devuelve basura ¿A que se debe si en el printf "Numero vectorizado" este se muestra bien?

pd: Estoy trabajando en MacOS Sierra y compilando con GCC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que, en este código,

```
int * vectorizar(int n){
  int numero[4];
  ...
```

crea un arreglo **local a la función vectorizar**; `numero` deja de existir en cuanto alcanzas el final de la función; mejor dicho, la CPU **reutiliza ese espacio para otras cosas**.

Aquí vamos a entrar en detalles sobre el funcionamiento interno:

Cada vez que tu llamas a una función, la CPU guarda ciertos datos en la pila, entre ellos posibles variables locales de la función que uses. Sucesivas llamadas van *empilando* datos en la pila. Al `retornar` de la función, dichos datos **no son borrados**; simplemente dejan de ser útiles en el contexto actual, y tu no tienes forma de acceder a ellos **salvo que algun puntero aún los referencie**.

Una vez que tu `retornas` de `vectorizar( )`, los datos **sigen en la misma posición de memoria**; no son borrados, y, por lo tanto, tu puntero `ejemplo` sigue apuntando a ellos.

Entonces, ¿ porqué la función `printf( )` puede acceder a ellos ? **De pura suerte**. Da la puñetera casualidad de que los argumentos pasados + las variables internas de esa función **no sobreescriben** los datos previos de la pila **antes de usarlos**.

¿ Y porqué falla `ascendente( )` ? pues porque **se te acabo la suerte**. Alguna de las llamdadas previas (alguno de los `printf( )` o la propia llamada a `ascendente( )` **sobreescriben** la zona de la pila en la que estaban esos datos. En el momento de sobreescribirlos, tu puntero `ejemplo` **aun** apunta a ellos; a partir de esa sobreescritura, dejan de tener el valor que tu esperas.

¿ Como lo soluciono ? pues usando **memoria dinámica** **o** creando el array `int numero[4]` **dentro** de `main` y pasando **2** argumentos a tu función `vectorizar( )`.

Comment: Gracias, sabia que tenia que ver con el tema de que la variable era local a la función pero como funcionaban los printf me extraño.

Comment: De hecho, si intento compilar tu código, mi compilador **avisa**: `warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return numero;` - la función devuelve la dirección de una variable local.