# Problema con variable y fopen VC++

Tags: c++

Ya llevo quebrándome la cabeza con este problema ya que si ocupo **Codeblocks** con **wingw** no me arroja ningún problema

```
char *getArchivoSalida(int num)
{
    char nombre[1024] = "";
    sprintf(nombre, "Imagenx%d.ppm", num);
    ofstream fs(nombre);
    fs.close();
    return nombre;
}

int binario(char *nombre, int n)
{
    FILE *entrada, *salida;
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
    char *archivoSalida = "";
    char formato[3];
    int height, width, depth;
    int widthCont = 1;
    entrada = fopen(nombre, "rb");
    if (entrada == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO SE PUDO ABRIR\n");
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    archivoSalida = getArchivoSalida(n);
    salida = fopen(archivoSalida ,"w+");
    fscanf(entrada, "%s", formato);
    /Continua abajo/
}
```

El problema es que en la linea de `salida = fopen(archivoSalida, "w+")` al ve el error en el compilador me aparece que la vaiable `FILE` salida contiene un valor null cosa que debe recibir el nombre del archivo.
Nose como se pierde, lo intenté colocalo como variable constante pero nada

El colmo es que si ingreso

```
salida = fopen("Imagenx1.ppm", "w+");
```

funciona a la perfección....

que está pasando, es poblema de vc++?

saludos

Edicion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error no será del tipo `intento de retornar una variable interna de la función` o algo así ?

Comment: Tienen toda la pinta de que nombre queda fuera del alcance de la funcion, has probado a crearlo reservando memoria en getArchivoSalida() o usando una variable global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los comentarios tienes la pista: estás devolviendo una variable **interna** de la función `getArchivoSalida( )`.

Eso quiere decir que, al llamar a esa función, obtienes una cadena **invalida** (mas correctamente, *de contenido indefinido*).

Al intentar el `fopen( )`, **NO** le estás pasando el `nombre`, que es lo que tu esperas, sino *algo* que no puedes controlar. En consecuencia, `fopen( )` falla, y devuelve `NULL`.

Ten presente que ningún compilador es erróneo. *contenido indefinido* quiere decir que *ambos* comportamientos son correctos. El problema no es el compilador.

De hecho, estoy **seguro** de que **ambos** compiladores te mostraran un *aviso* al compilar, del tipo `intento de retornar una variable interna de la función` o similar, o su equivalente en inglés.

En está pregunta
[Problema al enviar puntero a array como parametro a una función](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40803/problema-al-enviar-puntero-a-array-como-parametro-a-una-funci%C3%B3n/)
tienes una descripción mas detalla de tu problema, y algunas posibles soluciones.

Comment: Gracias, no me habia dado cuenta que de ese detalle, ya que estoy usando punteros a una variable interna de uan funcion esta desaparece al finalizar la funcion. Lo arregle colocando la Variable nombre[1024] como static. te pasastes

Comment: Si las respuestas te resultan útiles, considera *aceptarlas* (el simbolo del *check* a la izquierda) y/o votarlas positivamente (flechita arriba, a la izquierda, justo sobre el *check*).  Gracias.