# Porque no se me asigna la direccion de memoria de una cadena a un puntero?

Tags: c

Lo que quiero hacer es retornar la direccion de memoria de la cadena CADE que genero en la funcion y asignarla al puntero CADENA. Pero cuando lo ejecuto me marca el siguiente error y probe de solucionarlo pero sigue sin funcionarme.
ERROR: invalid conversion from `char' to`char*'

Por lo que entiendo es debido a que no puedo asignarlo ya que uno es char y el otro es un puntero a un char. Pero como es la solucion para que haga lo que explique antes? Muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * ingresa_cadena();





int main()
{ 
char *cadena;
cadena=ingresa_cadena();
printf ("La cadena ingresada es %c", cadena);




system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

char * ingresa_cadena()
{ 
 char cade[25];
 gets(cade);
 return (&cade); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código presenta varios fallos:

```
char *cadena;
...
printf ("La cadena ingresada es %c", cadena);
```

Declaras `cadena` como un **puntero**, pero luego intentas imprimir un **caracter**.

Tienes **2** soluciones:

Imprimir la cadena entera:

```
printf ("La cadena ingresada es %s", cadena);
//                               ^s
```

Imprimir un character (el primero):

```
printf ("La cadena ingresada es %c", *cadena);
//                                   ^*
```

Aparte de eso, haces:

```
char * ingresa_cadena( ) { 
  char cade[25];
  gets(cade);
  return (&cade);
}
```

Con eso, estas devolviendo un *arreglo* **local a la función**. Para no repetirme, te sugiero consultar [*mi respuesta*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43755/problema-con-variable-y-fopen-vc/43783#43783) a una pregunta anterior.